# Incorrect syntax near '('.?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview, sql-update

I have `ShowGrid()`, `RowEditing` and `RowCancelingEdit` but they are correct.

When executing the website I get this general error that I can not figure out:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '('.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_OnRowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
    Dim connStr, cmdStr As String
    connStr = "XXXXX"
    cmdStr = "UPDATE OrbitDates SET (JD=@JD,Xecl1=@Xecl1,Yecl1=@Yecl1,Zecl1=@Zecl1) WHERE ido=@ido;"
    Try
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ido", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JD", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Xecl1", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yecl1", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zecl1", GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Text)

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    ViewState("edit") = e.RowIndex
    ShowGrid()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use parentheses in your UPDATE statement:

```
cmdStr = "UPDATE OrbitDates SET JD=@JD,Xecl1=@Xecl1,Yecl1=@Yecl1,Zecl1=@Zecl1 WHERE ido=@ido;"
```

Comment: Great that got rid of the "Incorrect syntax near '('." error. Thanks.